# How to get a new list every time an element changes (the element being a certain index for every tuple in a list of tuples)

Tags: python

I have a list filled with lists like this one: ['L1045', 'u0', 'm0', 'BIANCA', 'They do not!'] and this one ['L1981', 'u16', 'm1', 'COLUMBUS', "I haven't given you much of a life."] parsed from the Cornell Movie Dialog Corpus, where the index 0 is the dialogue line ID, index 2 is the movie ID, and index 3 is the line itself. There are many lines from each movie, so many lists have identical items at index 2 (many 'm0's for example). They do not have every line in each movie, though, so the items at index 0 may fall into some patterns, but other numbers are absent (for example, there might be an 'L99,' 'L100,' 'L102' for a particular movie, but then there may be a gap from 103-179).

Basically, I'm trying to create a separate list of strings of each index 3 for all the sequential lines in each movie. So a separate list of lines for each separate "scene" for each movie.

I'm just having a very hard time getting there. I don't know if I should be creating a dictionary where each unique movie (index 2) has a 
unique key with a value consisting of a list of tuples, each with the line number and the line itself. Then doing some kind of counter to check whether there is a gap in the line numbers, etc, etc). If I go this route, I'm struggling even figuring out how to do this for each specific movie...

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Below is some code I know doesn't work but shows some of my initial thought processes:

```
movie_lines = 'DIRECTORYPATH/movie_lines.txt'
with open(movie_lines, "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as fh:
    lines_chunks = [line.split(" +++$+++ ") for line in fh]

number = 0
counter = 'm' + str(number)
new_list = []

for i in range(616):  
    number = 0
    counter = 'm' + str(number)

    for line in lines_chunks:
        if line[2] == counter:
            new_list.append([(line[2], line[0], line[4])])
        number += 1
```

Comment: 1. Those are not list of lists. 2. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Based on your description is this correct - assuming you have a huge spreadsheet you want to sort 1st on the "movieID" column and 2nd on the "lineID" column? Would be very helpful if you could share a sample piece of your raw data...

Comment: @Dino yes that's right. The raw files can be downloaded here [https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html] if you're interested. It consists of several txt files. The one I'm interested in is called movie_lines.txt, and it's basically just lines of information that I cleaned up and put into lists. Here's the first line: "L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!". The cleaned up version is in the body of my question.

Comment: @Austin I edited my question to make it a bit more clear as to your first point, thank you. I'm still stuck on just sketching out ideas. I'll provide some code that I know doesn't work but shows my early thought process on the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

I'd use a nested dictionary to store data:

`data = {'movie_id' : {'scene_id' : tuple(int(line_id), character, actual_line)}}`

This way if you want to retrieve all lines from a particular scene in a particular movie, you'll just need to call `data['movie']['scene']` and the return is a list of tuples.

Here's the code:

```
movie_lines = 'movie_lines.txt'
with open(movie_lines, "r") as f:
    lines = [line.split(' +++$+++ ') for line in f]

data = dict()

for line in lines:
    # line[0] --> line_id
    # line[1] --> scene_id
    # line[2] --> movie_id
    # line[3] --> character???
    # line[4] --> actual_line
    if not line[2] in data:
        data[line[2]] = {line[1]: [(int(line[0][1:]),line[3],line[4])]}
    elif not line[1] in data[line[2]]:
        data[line[2]][line[1]] = [(int(line[0][1:]),line[3],line[4])]
    else:
        data[line[2]][line[1]].append((int(line[0][1:]), line[3], line[4]))

# taking movie 'm0' and scene 'u0' as an example
test = data['m0']['u0']
test.sort()  # by default sort is done by first element in tuple
print(test)
```

`int(line[0][1:])` converts the line id "Lxxx" to an integer for ease of sorting later.

Output:

> [(49, 'BIANCA', 'Did you change your hair?\n'), (51, 'BIANCA', 'You might wanna think about it\n'), (165, 'BIANCA', 'Nowhere... Hi, Daddy.\n'), (179, 'BIANCA', "Now don't get upset. Daddy, but there's this boy... and I think he might ask...\n"), ..., (1021, 'BIANCA', 'Is that woman a complete fruit-loop or is it just me?\n'), (1045, 'BIANCA', 'They do not!\n'), (1051, 'BIANCA', 'Patrick -- is that- a.\n')]

Hope this could help you. Cheers.